# How to deploy to heroku dyno with nodejs with express web app and python script inside node_modules (specifically spacy-js)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, spacy, heroku-cli

So what I have is I'm using nodejs/express for website. I am also using another javascript module called spacy-js. To make spacy-js work, I have to run a python file in the spacy module like "python node_modules/spacy/api/server.py" in 1 terminal and then do "npm start" on another terminal so that spacy works on my website. Inside the module, it is specified that the server.py will run on port 8080. Finally, there is a separate requirements.txt inside the spacy-js module. Now, this website uses nodejs website and also runs a python file inside node_modules. How do I deploy this to heroku?